# Perform different calculation on each element of an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array. I need to perform a different calculation on each element. I thought I could do something like the following:

```
def calc(a, b, c)
    arr = [a, b, c]
    arr.map { |i| (i[0] * 600), (i[1] * 800), (i[2] * 1000) }
end

calc(5, 8, 15)
```

but this does not work. How can I perform different calculations on each element of a single array?

Comment: Feels like you are over complicating - why not `[a*600, b*800, c*1000]`

Comment: @FrederickCheung, i think this comment should be an answer

Comment: What do you expect for the answer to `calc(5, 8, 15)`?

Comment: add more details, what you exactly want you want each element simple multiply by hardcoded values then use @FrederickCheung suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some other implementations that might be helpful. By putting the multipliers into an array, we can use `zip` to connect the element in the input array with the appropriate multiplier value. In addition, that makes it simple to abstract the logic further by removing the multiplier values from the logic that does the multiplication (in `multiply_arrays` and `transform_arrays`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

VALUES = [1, 1, 1]
MULTIPLIERS = [600, 800, 1000]

def transform(*values)
  values.zip(MULTIPLIERS).map { |x, y| x * y }
end

def multiply_arrays(array1, array2)
  array1.zip(array2).map { |n1, n2| n1 * n2 }
end

def transform_arrays(array1, array2, method_name)
  array1.zip(array2).map { |n1, n2| n1.public_send(method_name, n2) }
end


p transform(*VALUES)                           # [600, 800, 1000]
p multiply_arrays(VALUES, MULTIPLIERS)         # [600, 800, 1000]
p transform_arrays(VALUES, MULTIPLIERS, :*)    # [600, 800, 1000]
```

If the calculations need to be substantially different (different operators, values, more complex logic), than I'd consider using an array of lambdas:

```
def transform_with_lambdas(values, transforms)
  values.zip(transforms).map do |value, transform|
    transform.(value)
  end
end

TRANSFORMS = [
  ->(x) { x *  600   },
  ->(x) { x +  100   },
  ->(x) { x /    3.0 },
]

p transform_with_lambdas(VALUES, TRANSFORMS)  # [600, 101, 0.3333333333333333]
```

Comment: +1 for demonstrating the use of zip and the short form of calling a lambda with the  some_lambda.(some_arg)  - could not find the documentation on that form, do you know were it is documented?

Comment: If you look at the API docs for `Proc#call` at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html#call it has a note saying "Note that prc.() invokes prc.call() with the parameters given. It’s a syntax sugar to hide "call"." I once tested and found that this will work with *any* object that responds to `call`, not just a Proc (including lambdas).

Comment: Thanks, I see it now

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which will help you to apply different operations on two different operands:

```
def calc(first_operand_arr, operator_arr, second_operand_arr)
  result_arr = []
  operator_arr.each_with_index do |o, i|
    result_arr << (first_operand_arr[i]).method(o).(second_operand_arr[i])
  end
  result_arr
end

calc([5, 8, 15], ['+', '-', '*'], [5, 3, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calc *arr
    ops = [600, 800, 1000]
    arr.map { |x| x * ops.shift }
end

calc(5, 8, 15)
  #=> [3000, 6400, 15000]
```

You could generalize this as follows:

```
def calc(*arr)
  arr.map { |op1, op2, m| op1.send(m, op2) }
end

calc [5, 6, :*], [2, 3, :+], [10, 8, :-]
  #=> [30, 5, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using a second array of lambda's that can be arbitrary functions of each entry in your main array.

```
operands = [1.0,2.0,3.0]

operations = [
              ->(e) { e * 10} ,
              ->(e) { e + 10 },
              ->(e) { e * e }
            ]

results = operands.each_with_index.map { |operand, index| operations[index].call(operand) }
puts results
```

**Edit**
I just noticed this is a really a variation on Keith Bennett's answer above,  I will leave it here, since it is different in how the lambda is retrieved from the array.

Comment: I don't think suggesting using the index to get both value and operation is helpful, since it's unnecessary complexity that `zip` avoids.